# What is the effect of not grounding a power supply to a servo?

Tags: servo

So I am working on a project which basically involves controlling a servo with a raspberry pi. I noticed that when I forgot to connect the ground cable (image below) the servo still whirred to life and in fact continued ticking and buzzing more noticeably than when I connected the ground cable. What is happening here and did my forgetfulness damage my servo/my pi? (as I cant get my servo to move but I think it is a software issue with RPIO being broken for RPi3)

[image: i was missing the connection where the red arrow is pointing]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Rpi3 is connected to a regulated USB power source, both the grounds, the servo power supply and the USB power source need to short so as to give a common reference signal for the whole circuit to work on.

Your reference(PWM) signal is coming with respect to the Rpi power supply ground but the servo is being supplied with a different 'common refernce signal'. Hence, the servo is not in 'sync' with the Rpi common reference and therefore the servo is still being fed with a supply but with a different ground and hence you see the servo ticking.